# FfmpegInterop UWP C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, uwp, windows-10-universal

I successfully build ffmpeg for ffmpeginterop and I added reference nodes to the dll in the .csproj file, however when I run my project as soon as FFmpegInteropMSS.CreateFFmpegInteropMSSFromStream(avStream, false, false) is executed I’m hit with a System.IO.FileNotFound exception. I did paste the ffmpeg dlls with the ffmpeginterop and also tried in the project dir with copy to output, no change. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Read more at https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/05/using-ffmpeg-in-windows-applications/#1CxJCd2mSDpMqiIP.99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not have all dll's copied into project and build action to content & copy always.

Thanks